# Contrain camera to rectangle while tracking multiple objects

Tags: c#, camera, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I'm making a 2D platformer that features a dynamic camera. The camera must track 4 players at once so that they're all on the screen. In addition the camera must not move beyond a predefined rectangle boundary. I've tried implementing it but I just can't seem to get the process of zooming the camera so that it's always close as possible to the four objects.

The general algorithm I have so far is 
 1. Define the viewing space by calculating a 2D axis aligned bounding box using the 4 object positions being tracked and use its center as a camera postion (or averaging)
2. Calculate an orthographic size by using the largest x OR y value using a vector from the camera's position to each object being tracked.

1. If the camera is beyond the camera's boundary calculate the excess amount and displace in the opposite direction.

This seems simple enough on paper but I can't seem to get a correct working implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just take the Average of the 4 players Position and use it as Camera Position, also check if the players are out of boundary and when they are, zoom out.

```
float x = 0;
float y = 0;

GameObject[] players = new GameObjects[5];
foreach(GameObject _ply in players)
{
  x += _ply.transform.position.x;
  y += _ply.transform.position.y;


}
x = x/players.Length;
y = y/players.Length;

foreach(GameObject _ply in players)
{
  if(_ply.transform.position.x > (x + (Screen.Width / 2)))
    //zoom out

  if(_ply.transform.position.y > (y + (Screen.Height / 2)))
    //zoom out


}
```

But you have to fix Zoomin.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been a bit clearer in the initial question. I've managed to calculate the camera position using the axis aligned bounding box and by averaging. The main issue I'm having is with the process of zooming so that it's close to the objects while being constrained to the area.

Comment: So you need just the zoom in and out function?